# Matrix of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, matrix-rank, trace

Let $\left(X_i\right)_{i}^{n}$ be a family of independant random variables that follow a Bernoulli schemes. Let $U$ and $M$ be
$$U=
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1\\
X_2\\ 
 \vdots\\
 X_n
\end{pmatrix}
\text{ and } 
M=U ^{t} \! U
$$

I've found that $Rank\left(M\right)$ also follows a Bernoulli scheme of parameter $p'=1-\left(1-p\right)^n$ and that $Trace\left(M\right)$ follows a Bernoulli law $B\left(n,p\right)$.
I would like to know, first if my results are right, and also if it was possible to excavate new results similar to this like the law of the determinant or even probability on its eigenvalue. ( It is always diagonalizable since it is symmetric with real entries )

Thanks

Comment: Determinant is always $0$ (n >1)

Comment: Can you explain ?

Comment: The matrix is rank $1$ the unique nonzero eigen value is $tr(M)$ and you have already the law of that.

Comment: The determinant of rank one matrix is $0$ if (n > 1)

Comment: So can i write that the charaeristic polynomial is $\displaystyle \chi_{M}\left(X\right)=X^{n-1}\left(X-\text{Tr}\left(M\right)\right)$ ? ( Youem : Yes i'm stupid xD thank you )

Comment: Yes exactly the characteristic polynomial is what you said